# Can I implement a FM Radio Rx on the the Spartan 3E kit?

Tags: fpga, xilinx, dsp, hdl, sdr

**Can I implement a FM Radio Rx on the the Spartan 3E kit?**

Starting Problems I am facing-

1. How do I interface the Antenna with the Spartan 3E kit?
2. Implementing the A/D converter.

Comment: Have you done a google research? http://www.rs-online.com/designspark/electronics/knowledge-item/designing-an-fm-receiver-demonstrates-the-flexibility-of-fpga-technology

Comment: thank u for the response, yes, i saw this post..did not help much as nothing about the implementation is given..

Answer (score 1):

Mirics has a nice chipset for FM SDR that includes the RF front-end, tuner and A/D and exports I/Q samples over USB.

Here's a nice discussion about the part:  http://www.reddit.com/r/RTLSDR/comments/2yjhvr/information_on_mirics_chipset_for_general_sdr/

I understand that this product uses the Mirics chip, but I have no experience with it myself:  http://sdrplay.com/

You should be able to connect this box to the Spartan FPGA board via USB using their provided drivers for Linux.